# Drupal service using json server

Tags: jquery, web-services, drupal-6

My question is how to generate hash key in jquery without using library or is there any way that don't pass hash code but use key authentication.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://mydomain.com/services/json-rpc",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
            "method":"node.get", 
            "params":{"hash":"c30eb6b7c256dc4888e2077d0fe44d49b63c07eae7a4bb9e595ad1410ab3992d","domain_name":"http://localhost/drupalclient","domain_time_stamp":"1350026093","nonce":"e0ace29286bdcf88b7f2","nid":44}
           },
            success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I include a js to generate hash code and now my problem solved. ;)